# What is the meaning of this line in Loch Lomond?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, folk

This verse of Loch Lomond is usually sung as :

> The wee birdies sing
>   And the wild flowers spring
>   And in sunshine the waters lie sleeping
>   But the broken heart it kens, nae second spring again
>   **and the waeful may cease there [sometimes from] their greeting**

Does this really mean that the woeful are gong to stop greeting people, or does it mean they will stop visting the lake? What does this mean? I doubt it's the former, because other form of this verse replaces "greeting" with "greiving", implying some kind of recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Greeting" is Scots for crying, so the woeful will cease their crying...

[Example link explaining](http://www.scotsman.com/heritage/people-places/scottish-word-of-the-week-greeting-1-3536474)